# Custom ActionBar text appearance in Android 4.3

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have customized the appearance of my app's title  on the action bar with the following code

```
<style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff2d2d2d</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
    <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

Anyway, everything worked quite alright in most of the devices I have tested (3 to be precised) but for 1, a device running Android 4.3 (Sony Xperia Z) where the style wasn't applied. I later tested it on an emulator running 4.3 and had the same result.

[image]

Is there a way I can fix this?

Here is the complete style for the app

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">

        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/RobotoTextViewStyle</item>
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/RobotoButtonStyle</item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_dark</item>

        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/nav_list_selector</item>

    </style>


    <style name="RobotoTextViewStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="RobotoButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Button">
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-light</item>
    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/myTheme.ActionBar.Text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_bar_bg</item>
        <item name="android:searchButtonText">SEARCH</item>
        <item name="android:editTextBackground">@drawable/apptheme_edit_text_holo_dark</item>

    </style>

    <style name="myTheme.ActionBar.Text" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ff2d2d2d</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">26sp</item>
        <item name="android:fontFamily">sans-serif-condensed</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: What's the problem? or should we guess what trouble you are running into? a screenshot or something similar would be helpful.

Comment: @Ahmad the style wasn't applied. wasn't that obvious enough?

Comment: No, it wasn't obvious. It could have been, that only a certain part wasn't or was applied. However. What Android versions where the devices running, that it did work on?

Comment: @Ahmad You do have a point there, my apologies.
It worked on 4.2.2, 4.1.2 and 4.4.2.
I will post screenshots soon to support the question

Comment: Hmm that's indeed strange.

Comment: @Ahmad screenshot added

Comment: Please post the full xml of your Theme and Action Bar style.

Comment: @PaulBurke I have added the full styles.xml

Answer (score 4):

For me this works like a charm. 
Let's make a custom view for action bar

res/layout/action_title_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:text=""
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textColor="@color/actionbar_text" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Set custom action bar in your activity onCreate

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // set action bar custom view
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mCustomActionView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_title_view, null);

    // assign the view to the actionbar
    getActionBar().setCustomView(mCustomActionView);

    ...
}
```

Now override the setTitle method of your activity

```
@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    mTitle = title;
    ((TextView) mCustomActionView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(mTitle);
    getActionBar().setTitle("");
}
```

Use setTitle method to set your custom action bar text. Hope this helps.

Comment: this generates an error for me `no resources filel that atches the given name: `

Comment: @Olayinka - you are right. i have updated my ans. please retry.

Comment: isn't this just putting the same theme in a support-v11 folder?? or is there something I am missing? care to explain why this may work?

Comment: i generally put separate files for different api levels, cz they have different attributes, and it works everytime

Comment: Why 11 for this one, if I may ask? Between, I tried but still got the same result

Comment: Have you tried using appCompat theme - parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"

Comment: i will post my appCompat implementation tomorrow.

Comment: that did the trick. thanks. I didn't know using custom layout for action bar is this easy, I would have done that.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that came up my mind when I read this post is that you might be using the different resources for every API version using the *values-v* folders.

A small example:
In the regular values folder I've set the text color to blue:

```
<style name="TextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/Blue</item>
```

In values-v11 I have a style to set in white the text color:

```
<style name="TextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
```

In values-v14 I have a style to set in red the text color:

```
<style name="TextMedium" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/Red</item>
```

Now, (you might 'v guessed it), depending on the api level your device is, that style is used. So if you run this code on API level 13, you text color will be white. For every api level lower than 11, blue is used.

Now there is another thing, if a style/resource is not present in the values-v folder of the SDK you are using, there will be refered to the second-best alternative (so if values-v16 has no reference for text colors, values-v14 will be used).

In your case, there should be a values-v17 (Jelly Bean, and up) that contains the style you refer to, if lower api level device try to access the style, it will not be present in there style folder, they will not use the resource from a higher Api level.

I'm not saying this is the cause of your problem, it's just a guess since you give no information about style versioning. Also, since it's Jelly Bean 4.3 and up that do work, you might be refering to features that got added in Api level 17

Comment: The thing is I am not using style versioning at all. I have one values folder which is `values`. My minimum sdk is 16.

Comment: In that case my answer is irrelevant for you. I'll just leave my question here for other users that come across this question.